# object (Car) Detection and segmentation

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment cars from image that consist of only one car and an easy background like 
[image]

[image]

but what I get from my implementation is this
[image]

and
[image]

respectively

but it works very easily on almost already segmented images like.
[image]

giving results like
[image]

The Code I am using is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

THRESH_TYPE=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV

def show(name,obj):
    cv2.imshow(name,obj)
    cv2.moveWindow(name, 100, 100) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def process_end(new):
    drawing = np.zeros(o.shape,np.uint8)     # Image to draw the contours
    contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(new,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)#find connected borders
    for cnt in contours:
        color = np.random.randint(0,255,(3)).tolist()  # Select a random color
        cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,color,2)
    print "processing done"
    return drawing

def process(name,path):
    global o
    print "Started!!! processing "+name
    ratio=1#change according to image size
    o=cv2.imread(path+name)#open image
    print type(o)
    show("original",o)
    w,h=o.shape[1]/ratio,o.shape[0]/ratio#resize ratio for width and height
    new=cv2.resize(o,(w,h))#resize image
    #show("Resized",new)
    new=cv2.cvtColor(new,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)#grey scale image
    show("grey",new)
    cv2.imwrite("grey.jpg",new)
    new1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(new,(5,5),0)#gaussians Blurs Image
    show("blurred1",new1)
    cv2.imwrite("gblur_"+name,new1)#save image
    new2 = cv2.medianBlur(new,7)#Median Blurs Image
    show("blurred2",new1)
    cv2.imwrite("mblur_"+name,new2)#save image
    #new=cv2.equalizeHist(new,)#do image histogram equalisation to better the contrast
    #show("hist equal otsu",new)
    ##cv2.imwrite("otsu_"+name,new)#save image

    a,new=cv2.threshold(new,0,255,THRESH_TYPE | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)#OTSU thresholding
    show("otsu",new)
    cv2.imwrite("otsu_"+name,new)#save image
    return new,name



new,name=process("car9.jpg","C:\\Users\\XOR\\Desktop\\file\\")#Change the Name and path accordingly
new=cv2.Canny(new, 100,200)#canny edge detection technique
show("canny",new)
cv2.imwrite("canny_"+name,new)#save image
new=process_end(new)
show("blobed",new)
cv2.imwrite("blob_"+name,new)#save image
new=cv2.Sobel(new,-1,1,0,3,BORDER_WRAP)
show("sobel",new)
cv2.imwrite("sobel_"+name,new)#save image
```

I have tried the watershed algorithm (on matlab) too but it also doesn't help.
I'm looking for a way to segment the first two images that gives a result similar to third one.

Comment: could you please check my profile and email me.  I solved another one of your problems, but you took it down yesterday as i was posting the solution! (substring problem)

Comment: @michael I cant find your e-mail...cant you post it here?

Comment: michael.b.paulson@gmail.com

Comment: @michael I have mailed the problem to you

Comment: Surprisingly, nobody suggesting to use semantic segmentation until now. FYI, further, segmenting target car from multiple cars in an image may become challenging.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, **Detection** and **Segmentation** are two different problems. First decide which one you wanna do.

If your problem is '*Car Detection From Single Image*', you can't do it by segmentation. You can segment image into parts and by using another approach (take the biggest segmented region) you can find the car in the image, but I'm sure it won't work for all images. That's why watershed algorithm didn't work. Segmentation algorithms just segments the image doesn't give you particular object/region in it. For example if you look at the image shown, it is segmented into regions, but you can't know which region is which.

[image],

If you want to detect cars in images, you need to approach this problem as object detection problem. This [link](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/) will provide you some information about car detection problem. It has two papers about it and a database to test approaches.

Hope it helps..

Comment: thanks @guneykayi.
Isn't there any simple way to find the solution without reading a research paper and then learning all the algorithms mentioned there because right now I am more concentrating on machine learning (because of my project)?

Comment: Life is not that simple! If you are concentrating on machine learning you should read those papers and learn some of the algorithms anyway!

Comment: OpenCV provides tools for advanced descriptors like HOG, and it does also provide tools for training classifiers (like SVM)...

Comment: @guneykayim: Very good explanation. It's pitty, I didn't come across your posts earlier. And thanks for the link!

Comment: I know I am late, today we have semantic segmentation, you can know what are the segmented objects by this awesome tool.

Answer (score 3):

For car detection I would use latern svm detector with the "Car" model:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

Comment: actually I will have to use neural networks in my system for car classification(sedans,suvs,hatchbacks) I am looking for some coding algorithm rather than training my system first for object detection and then for classification but I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess like @GilLevi says once you have learned a set of global features for cars for the detection problem, one can produce a sublabelling of the classes of cars based on more specific features: like color distribution, shape templates, logos etc, and becomes another class of semantic image segmentation. You would still largely gain from the learning part than focussing on a segmentation specific approach which would need many variables to tune. Another dataset with cars: http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/marszalek/data/ig02/