# Pre-trained HOG LBP model for vehicle detection

Tags: opencv, gradient, feature-descriptor

Is there any pre-trained HOG or LBP descriptor for detecting vehicles in OpenCV?  I need it for comparing different algorithms for detecting cars from video streams.

Comment: Front? Side? Back? Afair Ive seen a a car-side-detector here on SO 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Micka where on SO? post the link plz

Comment: Had to search again myself: not pretrained but provides training images: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/ found in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590444/object-car-detection-and-segmentation/19591713#19591713 which was linked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648125/number-of-objects-in-an-image